# libtorch : How to create a gpu tensor base on data_ptr?

Tags: c++, libtorch

create a gpu tensor base on data_ptr?

```
  int main{
        auto ten=torch::randn({3,10},torch::kCuda);
        auto p=ten.data_ptr<float>();//I believe "p" is a gpu pointer?
        auto ten2=torch::from_blob(p,{3,10});//ten2's device=cpu,that's the problem
        cout<<ten2;//then I got error:"interrupted by signal 11 SIGSEGV"
    }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should declare `ten2`'s device to be GPU, like that :

```
  int main{
    auto ten=torch::randn({3,10},torch::kCUDA);
    auto p=ten.data_ptr<float>();//I believe "p" is a gpu pointer?
    auto options = torch::TensorOptions().device(torch::kCUDA);
    auto ten2=torch::from_blob(p,{3,10}, options);
    cout<<ten2;
}
```

On a side note, be careful when you use `from_blob`, the resulting tensor does not take ownership on the underlying memory. So if `ten` goes out of scope, it will free its memory which is also `ten2`'s underlying data. If you know that `ten` will go out of scope before `ten2`, you should make a call to clone :

```
auto ten2=torch::from_blob(p,{3,10}, options).clone();
```

Comment: It should be `torch::kCUDA`

Comment: is there a way to do this in python?